# Width of input fields is different between two orgs - DEV and PROD see screenshots attached

Tags: inputfield

I am trying to figure out how to make the width longer for some input fields on a record I am trying to create in PROD.

See screenshots attached of the difference.

enter image description here[image]

[image]

Let me know what can be done to fix. I am hoping its nothing to extensive. I want the fields to look like the second image.

Thanks,

Chantel

Comment: could you modify your question and clarify if this is a Record/Global Action, Screen Flow or Aura/LWC code? If it is code, could you add it to the question?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the page layout you have in the two environments is different. To allow fields to take up the full width of the page, you need to create a new section in the page layout. The steps to do this are available in this help article: [Create a new section in a page layout](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385416&type=1). When you create the section you'll have the ability to set the Layout to '1-column' which will allow the fields within it to span the entire page.

[image]

You can also disable the section header being displayed by unchecking the 'Display Section Header On' options for both the Detail and Edit pages, so that the user can't see that these fields are within a new section.

Comment: MacElrich Thanks. I was able to fix this by making the section a 1 column layout.

Comment: @Chantel that's great, glad I could help! To help others that might face the same issue in the future, it would be great if you could accept this answer if possible.

Comment: I have accepted the answer